# Issue with ONLY IE8 using Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8

Issue with ONLY IE8 using Google Maps V3

```
myMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Not sure where to begin diagnosing this issue..

see [here](http://www.providence.org/resources/Oregon/pmg/clinics/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a trailing comma on line 250 in your myLocationMeta array. That will cause issues in IE.

I'd check to make sure you don't have any other trailing commas.

Comment: I changed several things, but i think this was the FIX! thnx!

Comment: dawnerd thank you for this!  I have been searching for weeks for the solution to this IE8 google maps snafu, and although I've seen mention of 'trailing commas' elsewhere, it didn't sink in that that was my problem until I read this thread.  Thanks a million, it's a huge relief to have this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to point to an error on this line: clinics.js #259

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLocations[i][1], myLocations[i][2]);
```

"1 is null or not an object"

which is likely because you've exceeded your index (out of bounds).

If you have a trailing comma in your Array, you may have a "null" item in the last position.

Comment: Yep, but I logged out the data and its all there :\